# Is pointer-difference a valid way to find the index of an element in a vector within a range-based for loop?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Is it valid to use pointer-difference to find the index of an element within a range-based for loop?

A number of questions have been asked here concerning using indices and range-based loops together, but they almost all say to not use range-based loops if you also need the index of an element. But it seems like, at least for `std::vector`, `std::array`, and other containers which are contiguous in memory, you could use pointer differences to find the index of the element, provided you're iterating over element references. For example:

```
// Prints the indices of all elements for which Foo::bar is true.
void Example(const std::vector<Foo>& v) {
  for (const auto& e : v) {
    if (e.bar()) {
      auto index = &e - v.data(); // Valid???
      std::cout << index << std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

The above code compiles and runs correctly, but I'm not completely certain of its validity. Can any language lawyers confirm or deny whether this is an acceptable method to find the index of the element?

In addition, is it safe to assume that if a container has a `data()` member, then its elements are contiguous in memory, and is therefore safe to use with this approach?

Comment: I _believe_ that it is valid to take the address of a reference in order to get a pointer to the referred-to object or element, yes.

Comment: _In addition, is it safe to assume that if a container has a data() member, then its elements are contiguous in memory, and is therefore safe to use with this approach?_ It's true for vectors and strings, certainly.

Comment: Yes, since they are in the same "array". Perhaps this would render fewer warnings about pointer arithmetics though: `auto index = std::distance(std::addressof(v[0]), std::addressof(e));`

Comment: It's only legal, per [`[expr.add]/4.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#4), if `&e` is an array element, _id est_ if `std::vector` internal implementation employs arrays to unsure memory continuity. You can't get more pedantic than that!

Comment: I vaguely recall that `std::vector` must employ arrays and ensure memory continuity.  I cannot cite chapter-and-verse from the standard.

Comment: ... and if `Foo` != `bool` :D

Comment: @YSC Does that mean that if the `vector` internally does `malloc` and then individual placement `new`s it's not valid, but if it does a `malloc` + an array placement `new` it is valid?

Comment: @Eljay You're right, it is implied by [`[iterator.concept.contiguous]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.contiguous#2)

Comment: @Ted Pretty sure YSC is referring to `vector<bool>` being an array of packed bits.

Comment: @user4581301 I hope so, but I've gotten my illusions shattered many times before - just when I think that I know how something works :-)

Comment: @TedLyngmo See comment from Eljay and my reply to it;)

Comment: @YSC Ah, cool. I think I can breath again. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the underlying iterator meets the requirements of the LegacyContiguousIterator (C++17), then yes.  This requirement indicates that `*(itr + n)` is equivalent to `*(addressof(*itr)+n)`.

This is from https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ContiguousIterator

C++20 replaced it with the [contiguous_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/contiguous_iterator) concept.

The Cppreference page indicates `vector<bool>` does not meet the above concepts, but all other vectors do.  As do string, string_view, array, and the iterators for the begin/end overloads for valarray.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is such a weird exception to everything.

Answer (score 2):

```
auto index = &e - v.data(); // Valid???
```

Unless `Foo` is an alias to `bool`, **yes**.

---

`&e` and `v.data()` having pointer type, [`[expr.add]/5`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.add#5) applies:

> When two pointer expressions `P` and `Q` are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as `std​::​ptrdiff_­t` in the `<cstddef>` header (`[support.types.layout]`).
>
> (5.2)
> Otherwise, if `P` and `Q` point to, respectively, array elements `i` and `j` of the same array object `x`, the expression `P - Q` has the value `i−j`.

So, unless `e` or `v.data()` are not part of the same array object, this is well-defined. This could happen if `Foo` is an alias for `bool`, otherwise this condition is met per [`vector.overview/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector#overview-2) ensuring [`[container.requirements.general]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements.general#def:container,contiguous), itself ensuring [`[iterator.concept.contiguous]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/iterator.concept.contiguous#2):

> Let `a` and `b` be dereferenceable iterators and `c` be a non-dereferenceable iterator of type `I` such that `b` is reachable from `a` and `c` is reachable from `b`, and let `D` be `iter_­difference_­t<I>`.
> The type `I` models *contiguous_­iterator* only if
>
> (2.2) `to_­address(b) == to_­address(a) + D(b - a)`, and
> (2.3) `to_­address(c) == to_­address(a) + D(c - a)`.

---

> In addition, is it safe to assume that if a container has a data() member, then its elements are contiguous in memory, and is therefore safe to use with this approach?

We could construct weird situations where it weren't safe, but unless you do some really exotic things you're safe to go!

Comment: Another situation where it could be invalid would be if a [user-defined template specialization for `std::vector<Foo>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)  was made to make it invalid, but let us not go that route please.